# How to create if and catch (exception)for this code of scrapy

Tags: python, pandas, scrapy

so I want to scrape the data of multiple URLs and retrieve all the information. but I can only scrape from 1 URL if more than 1 URL will be an error (list index out of range). and I was given the info that use try and catch. what should be like for the syntax itself?

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider): name = "quotes"

def start_requests(self):
    urls = [
       # 'https://jdih.kaltimprov.go.id/produk_hukum/detail/9ef7f994-9db4'
        
    ]
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    yield{
        'Kategori':response.xpath('//*[@class="text-left"]/text()')[0].extract(), 
        'Nomor':response.xpath('//*[@class="text-left"]/text()')[1].extract(),
        'Judul':response.xpath('//*[@class="text-left"]/text()')[2].extract().strip(),
        'Tanggal Diterapkan':response.xpath('//*[@class="text-left"]/text()')[3].extract(),
        'Tanggal Diundangkan':response.xpath('//*[@class="text-left"]/text()')[4].extract(),
        'Keterangan Status':response.xpath('//*[@class="text-left"]/p/text()')[0].extract(),
        'Statistik View':response.xpath('//*[@class="text-left"]/text()')[5].extract(),
        'Statistik Download':response.xpath('//*[@class="text-left"]/text()')[6].extract(),
        'Katalog': response.xpath('//*[@class="text-left"]/p/span/text').extract(),
        'Abstraksi' :response.xpath('//*[@class="text-left"]/p/text()')[1].extract(),
        'Lampiran': response.css('body > section > div > div > div > div.row > div.col-3 > a::attr(href)').extract()  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the problem of scraping multiple urls. It's the problems of your xpath selector. For every element, you give a xpath to select an element from a list. If there is no text to extract and no lists, the "out of range" error will exist.

I have tried your code and add two urls:

```
class QuestionSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'question'
allowed_domains = ['jdih.kaltimprov.go.id']
start_urls = ['https://jdih.kaltimprov.go.id/produk_hukum/detail/9ef7f994-9db4',
    'https://jdih.kaltimprov.go.id/produk_hukum/detail/5d0c7c0c-aa58']

def parse(self, response):
    yield{
    'Kategori':response.xpath('//*[@class="text-left"]/text()')[0].extract(), 
    'Nomor':response.xpath('//*[@class="text-left"]/text()')[1].extract(),
    'Judul':response.xpath('//*[@class="text-left"]/text()')[2].extract().strip(),
    'Tanggal Diterapkan':response.xpath('//*[@class="text-left"]/text()')[3].extract(),
    'Tanggal Diundangkan':response.xpath('//*[@class="text-left"]/text()')[4].extract(),
    'Keterangan Status':response.xpath('//*[@class="text-left"]/p/text()')[0].extract(),
    'Statistik View':response.xpath('//*[@class="text-left"]/text()')[5].extract(),
    'Statistik Download':response.xpath('//*[@class="text-left"]/text()')[6].extract(),
    'Katalog': response.xpath('//*[@class="text-left"]/p/span/text').extract(),
    'Abstraksi' :response.xpath('//*[@class="text-left"]/p/text()')[1].extract(),
    'Lampiran': response.css('body > section > div > div > div > div.row > div.col-3 > a::attr(href)').extract()  
    }
```

It gives me an error:

```
 File "C:\Users\30463\desktop\quetsion3spider\quetsion3spider\spiders\question.py", line 17, in parse
'Keterangan Status':response.xpath('//*[@class="text-left"]/p/text()')[0].extract(),
File "D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\parsel\selector.py", line 70, in __getitem__
o = super(SelectorList, self).__getitem__(pos)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This second line shows the problem of selector.
Hope this can help you.